# Changing bar graph colors in Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I am struggling with a lesson in our book where we have to change the colors in a bar graph. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. There is no error message the colors are just printing black.

```
import turtle
tess = turtle.Turtle()

def draw_bar(t, height):

    t.begin_fill() 
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(height)
    t.write(" "+ str(height))

    t.right(90)
    t.forward(40)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(height)
    t.penup()
    t.left(90)
    t.end_fill() 
    t.forward(10)
    t.pendown()

    tess.pensize(3)

    if xs is 48:
        tess.color("blue")
    if xs is 117:
        tess.color("yellow")

wn = turtle.Screen() 
wn.bgcolor("lightgreen")



xs = [48,117,200,240,160,260,220]

for a in xs:
    draw_bar(tess, a)

wn.mainloop()
```

This is what I have so far.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think you have to place the color of the bar before begin_fill

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format the code in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to have a color assigned before you begin_fill(). Because the computer is like: "Well, I'll fill the box, but I don't have a color", so it uses the default of black.

The if statement you provided doesn't make sense, so I moved it up in the function and modified it where you can examine the height within the function. Instead of using if/else, I'd recommend dictionaries.

This new code works:

```
import turtle
tess = turtle.Turtle()

def draw_bar(t, height):

    # Select Color
    if height is 48:
        color = "blue"
    elif height is 117:
        color = "yellow"
    else:
        color = "black"

    # Assign color
    t.color(color)

    # The rest of your code
    t.begin_fill() 
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(height)
    t.write(" "+ str(height))

    t.right(90)
    t.forward(40)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(height)
    t.penup()
    t.left(90)
    t.end_fill() 
    t.forward(10)
    t.pendown()

    tess.pensize(3)

wn = turtle.Screen() 
wn.bgcolor("lightgreen")


xs = [48,117,200,240,160,260,220]

for a in xs:
    draw_bar(tess, a)

wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: That is what I had before and it works for coloring the entire bar graph, but I need to color the individual bars based on what value of the number and nothing I have tried has worked.

Comment: @DMondi Check out the latest edit. Basically, I moved your 'if' statement up in the function, and placed if else condition to handle the varying blocks.

Comment: @DMondi So...what happened?